# Creating a listner to multiple elements on Closure

Tags: javascript, events, closures

I'm using Closure for the first time after using jQuery for a long time.

I'm having problems with creating a listener for multiple objects that I get from getElementsByClass(). Any idea how I can do that in closure?

```
  goog.events.listen(
      goog.dom.getElementsByClass('clone'),
      goog.events.EventType.CLICK,
      function(e) {
          alert('hi');
      }
  );
```

I get the following error for above code:

Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'attachEvent'

EDIT: I got this working by the following code. However, I'm not too sure, if this is the most efficient way of doing it:

```
  var clone_buttons = goog.dom.getElementsByClass('clone');
  for (var i = 0; i < clone_buttons.length; i++) {
      goog.events.listen(
          clone_buttons[i],
          goog.events.EventType.CLICK,
          function(e) {
              alert('hi');
          }
       );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not using closures anywhere in the code your provided. If you want the most efficient code then you should store commonly used properties in local variables:

```
var clone_buttons = goog.dom.getElementsByClass('clone');
var length = clone_buttons.length;
var events = goog.events;
var CLICK = events.EventType.CLICK;

for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    events.listen(
        clone_buttons[i],
        CLICK,
        function(e) {
            alert('hi');
        }
    );
}
```

You can read more about closures here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12931785/783743

You can read about performance boosting tips here: http://jonraasch.com/blog/10-javascript-performance-boosting-tips-from-nicholas-zakas